# Revolution slider animation is not working in chrome BUT in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, animation

I have purchased revolution slider for my WordPress site. I have added some animation on text and images using revolution slider but the animations are not working on my Chrome, but on my Firefox & IE working properly.

On my chrome browser, texts and images are fade-in and fade-out, but I want animation which is working properly in Firefox.

Can any body tell me the issue?

Comment: Please post a link to the plugin you purchased, and ideally some sample code indicating how you are using it. Without this info it is really hard for us to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Revolution Slider - Premium responsive slider 4.3.6.

Comment: stackoverflow is not permitting me to submit the whole js code due to large amount of characters.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem...I reinstalled a fresh version of the plugin and it seemed to clear the problem. I have auto-updated the plugin a few times and I think it just didn't update properly. I didn't have to replace any files with an old version or anything. Edit: The version I'm using is 4.1.4...not the newest version 4.5.01...so perhaps the newest version is the issue).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. But I replaced js files with an older version of this plugin (responsive slider 4.1.1). Now it's working fine for me. But I'm not sure this is the correct way to solve this problem.